# MySQL INSERT Query - No longer works

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I am having an issue with an INSERT query that used to work but, as the title suggests, it's stopped working.

Here is the offending (or not so offending) code:

```
$qryd = "INSERT INTO 
         trans_deposits (login, walletadd, depamount, tickamount, recadd) 
         VALUES
         ('$login', '$walletadd', '$thefee', '$ticketamount', '$recaddress')";
$resultd = @mysql_query($qryd);
session_write_close();
```

... but more importantly... I accidentally deleted the original table (trans_deposits) so I created another table with the same table and column names etc. After which, the query no longer worked. - I don't see how, but could this have caused an issue?

I've tried the `mysql_error()` "trick" but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Try add dots to separate variables. ' . $login . ', ' . $walletadd . '

Comment: @sczdavos that shouldn't be necessary for simple variables. I would be a problem if he were using associative array variables.

Comment: You're suppressing the warnings/errors with `@`.  Try $resultd = mysql_query($qryd) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: If it worked before, I'd take a look at the table.

Comment: What's the error you're seeing?

Comment: You should turn debugging on in PHP.  However, you could try printing out $qryd and copying and pasting into mysql to see what the error is.

Comment: Try renaming the table and seeing if it works then?

Comment: You can also try echo the query and paste it into phpmyadmin.

Comment: post SHOW CREATE TABLE trans_deposits

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies guys and awsome help. I've fixed it but you'll hate me when I tell you that it was a major schoolboy error... Whitespace at start of two fields in my Database. (Won't let it happen again *sitting in the naughty corner.

Answer (score 0):

```
$qryd = "INSERT INTO trans_deposits(login, walletadd, depamount, tickamount, recadd) VALUES('$login', '$walletadd', '$thefee', '$ticketamount', '$recaddress')";
$resultd = mysql_query($qryd); //remove @
//For INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error. 
if (!$resultd) {
    echo "Error! ", mysql_error(); //Read the text of the error message
}
```